# jQuery/javascript slideshow on page background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a trivial question and I've searched for it last 2 hours and have got a lot of results. My problem is I've to create a slideshow with background images. But unfortunately none of them worked 100% for me. The last piece of code I was trying is,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images=new Array('images/home.png','images/home02.png','images/home03.png');
    var nextimage=0;

    doSlideshow();

    function doSlideshow()
    {
        if(jQuery('.slideshowimage').length!=0){
            jQuery('.slideshowimage').fadeOut(500,function(){slideshowFadeIn();jQuery(this).remove()});
    }
    else{
        slideshowFadeIn();
    }
}
function slideshowFadeIn(){
    jQuery('body').prepend(jQuery('<img class="slideshowimage" src="'+images[nextimage++]+'" style="display:none;z-index:-1">').fadeIn(500,function(){setTimeout(doSlideshow,3000);}));
    if(nextimage>=images.length)
       nextimage=0;
}
```

The slideshow is fine but as you see prepending them image to body doesn't make it background instead takes separate space for it. I've tried setting `z-index:-1` and

```
src=jQuery('<img class="slideshowimage" src="'+images[nextimage++]+'" style="display:none;z-index:-1">').fadeIn(500,function(){setTimeout(doSlideshow,3000);});
jQuery('body').css('backgroundImage','url('+src+')';
```

in `slideshowFadeIn()` function, but none of them work. I also tried supersized and some other plugin but they are not the best fit for what I want.

I've been trying for hours and now need some help. Thanks a lot!

Edit: JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/TtFmr/

Comment: Would it take much work to quickly create a jsfiddle out of it, so that I or someone else could mess around with it? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Joseph: Sorry for my late. [fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/TtFmr/) added to the question.

Comment: Try the answer that I added below... @Fallen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly... you are trying to put the slideshow behind the text?

If so then try this http://jsfiddle.net/TtFmr/4/

```
 img.slideshowimage {
     z-index: -1;
     position: absolute;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     display: block;
 }
```

There are many ways to position your slideshow, but the "correct" way of positioning it would depend on your specific situation.

Comment: well you set style for `img`, but there are some other images on body those also will get changed. Could you suggest any work around please?

Comment: @Fallen http://jsfiddle.net/TtFmr/4/ Make sure you use "img.slideshowimage" verses "img" ... I included this in my answer but forgot to include it in the jsfiddle... I updated my jsfiddle link